# Get last value entered past a specific row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have been on this a couple of days and I cannot get my head around this ... I use a spreadsheet to track the number of miles traveled by drivers and I want to work out how many miles a driver has traveled between 2 specified dates. Here is the spreadsheet.

[image]

Now using this formula I can easily find out the milages I start with.

```
= MIN(FILTER('Sheet1'!C2:C, 'Sheet1'!A2:A >= START_DATE, 'Sheet1'!A2:A <= END_DATE))
```

However, if I use a similar formula for the milages traveled up to the END_DATE I do not get the piece of information I need.

```
= MAX(FILTER('Sheet1'!C2:C, 'Sheet1'!A2:A >= START_DATE, 'Sheet1'!A2:A <= END_DATE))
```

So let's say I want to find out how many miles the driver traveled between June 18th and June 24 the first formula return the correct value

```
1690
```

However, the second one returns the value

```
1772
```

without taking account the miles traveled the late shift. Is there a way to get that entry?

Many thanks for all your inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(QUERY({IF(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A) <= MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!B2:B)), 
 ROW(Sheet1!A2:A))), VLOOKUP(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A), FILTER({ROW(Sheet1!A2:A), Sheet1!A2:A},
 LEN(Sheet1!A2:A)), 2), ), Sheet1!C2:C}, 
 "select Col2 
  where Col1 >= "&DATEVALUE(F1)&" 
    and Col1 <= "&DATEVALUE(F2), 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: wow, that was quick! and that is only to work out the max value of the END_DATE, correct?

Comment: @Danny you can use it for MIN too if you change MAX to MIN like:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(QUERY({IF(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A) <= MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!B2:B)), 
 ROW(Sheet1!A2:A))), VLOOKUP(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A), FILTER({ROW(Sheet1!A2:A), Sheet1!A2:A},
 LEN(Sheet1!A2:A)), 2), ), Sheet1!C2:C}, 
 "select Col2 
  where Col1 >= "&DATEVALUE(F1)&" 
    and Col1 <= "&DATEVALUE(F2), 0)))`

Comment: awesome! but I am having some issue with my date as on the reporting sheet it is display as "dd/mm". is there a conversion I can apply before handing it to the DATEVALUE function?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot as it is work related. I have tried DATEVALUE(DATE(YEAR(F1), MONTH(F1), DAY(F1)) but it doesn't work. Basically you can format the date from the drop down menu as "dd/mm" only

Comment: @Danny here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0bh0.png

Comment: it works! I must have missed a parentese ... DATEVALUE(DATE(YEAR(F1), MONTH(F1), DAY(F1)))

Comment: it was super helpful! just needed a tiny tweak due to the formatting of the date, thank you ever so much!

Comment: how would the formula change to evaluate the EARLY and LATE shift separately for a specific day?

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(QUERY({IF(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A) <= MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!B2:B)), ROW(Sheet1!A2:A))), VLOOKUP(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A), FILTER({ROW(Sheet1!A2:A), Sheet1!A2:A}, LEN(Sheet1!A2:A)), 2), ), Sheet1!B2:C}, "select Col3 where Col2 = '"&F3&"' and Col1 >= "&DATEVALUE(F1)&" and Col1 <= "&DATEVALUE(F2), 0)))` where F3 will be either EARLY or LATE

Comment: that works like a charm! although I didn't quite get it how your formulas work.

Comment: much appreciated!

Comment: your "late" values do not have a date in A column so what this formula does it basically copies down the las date over empty rows until a new date is found and so on. you can see it if you run this fx: `=ARRAYFORMULA({IF(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A) <= MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!B2:B)), ROW(Sheet1!A2:A))), VLOOKUP(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A), FILTER({ROW(Sheet1!A2:A), Sheet1!A2:A}, LEN(Sheet1!A2:A)), 2), ), Sheet1!B2:C})`

Comment: that explains why I get #N/A errors. some vehicles may stop for maintenance for a period of time or some of them have arrived after so when I select a range of dates when one of this condition is true I get the error

Comment: I am going to share a copy of the spreadsheet, stripped down of confidential data, so you can see what I mean by that. but how can I do that?

Comment: do what? share a copy of your sheet? - paste it here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dD5ETf4-2Sc-7z1EmcuquY7WqZury3jXqI1sQwkntL4/edit#gid=0

Comment: there you go https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J4fdLfex2EXFL3ZPpjqwPWXegrRRJLLgpEi9Nu4_DUE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: try again https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ggDCPEHUcrtCkCoGVW_t9O96uOgEp-MvndnSLC6hqdg

Comment: for the vehicle that I started monitoring after, I could simply add an IF statement that is: IF (1st Date < To_Date, 0, ARRAYFORMULA …)